# How to use RequireJS ? Error: " Module name "child_process" has not been loaded yet for context: Use require([])"?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, xml, browser

I included the required **"Requirejs"** scripts in **"index.html"** but how to code so that it calls my **"server.js"** file and that executes **"bash.sh"** file.

I have included all the Requirejs files and included them in my directory too.

index.html

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>THE XMLHttpRequest</h2>
      <p id="demo1"></p>
      <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>

      <script type = "text/javascript">

         function loadDoc() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
               if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                  document.getElementById("jsId").src = 'server.js';
                  //console.log(xhttp.responseText);
               }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "server.js", true);
            xhttp.send();

            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
               if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                  document.getElementById("demo1").textContent = this.responseText;
                  //console.log(xhttp.responseText);
               }  
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "file.txt", true);
            xhttp.send();

         }
      </script>

      <script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/comments/require.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" id = "jsId"></script>
      <script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/r.js"></script>

   </body>
</html>

<!-- browser-sync start --server --files "**/*" -->
```

server.js

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
var yourscript = exec('./bash.sh', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
   console.log(`${stdout}`);
   console.log(`${stderr}`);
   if (error !== null) {
      console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
   }
});
```

In **"index.html"** i have included the Require.js "r.js" and "require.js" links but how to code the " **Use require([])**  error" part so that it calls the **"server.js"** file.?